# How to pass and store information through methods

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In the following example when the screen in touched a method is called that passes a number to the view controller that is stored by MyViewController. Only problem the view controller doesn't store the number since I want to use it later in another method. Please help. Thank you.

MyViewController.h

```
@class MyView;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
     int number;
}

-(void)assignNumber(int)sentNumber;

@property int number;
```

MyViewController.m

```
-(void)loadView {
    MyView *aView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:wholescreen];
    self.view = aView;
    [aView release]; 
}

-(id)initWithNibName...... {
    number = 0;
}

-(void)assignNumber:(int)sentNumber {
    number = sentNumber;
}
```

MyView.h & MyView.m

Default with TouchesBegin, when touched `[viewController assignNumber:5];`

Comment: What check have you run to determine whether or not 5 is being stored in number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't declare @synthesize, you won't be able to access number from outside of the viewController internals. Try adding

```
@synthesize number;
```

to the top of MyView.m; This creates setters and getters. then, you can replace your

```
[viewController assignNumber:5];
```

call with

```
[viewController setNumber:5];
```

and access it with either `viewController.number` or `[viewController number]`.

Comment: `@synthesize` merely tells the compiler to implement accessors for a property. You must have already declared the property in the class's `@interface` (in the header file), and doing *that* is what exposes the property to objects of other classes. Conversely, as long as you declare the property (or its accessor methods individually) in the `@interface`, you can implement the accessors however you want—make the compiler do it (`@synthesize`) or implement them yourself; it'll appear no different to other objects that use the property.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to @synthesize the variable number in your ViewController implementation.